# Insert data to MySql DB and display if insertion is success or failure

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting data to a MySQL DB, In case if the insertion fails i need to give an appropriate error message indicating so. According to my code below i will be `Echo-ing` the message `Inserted` if the insertion was success or failure.

What i want to do is to echo the `Inserted` message only when the data insertion is a success, and return `fail` if it fails. How can i modify my code to do so ?

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("swm_database") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("INSERT INTO PEOPLE (NAME ) VALUES ('COLE')")or die(mysql_error()); 

echo "Inserted";
?>
```

Comment: the answers below already state what you should do, but think about using mysqli or PDO rather than the mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO PEOPLE (NAME ) VALUES ('COLE')"));
if($result)
{
echo "Success";

}
else
{
echo "Error";

}
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the book [PHP and MySQL for Dynamic Web Sites (4th edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321784073)

**Example:**

```
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

For simple queries like **INSERT**, **UPDATE**, **DELETE**, etc. (which do not return records), the `$r` variable—short for result—will be either **TRUE** or **FALSE**, depending upon whether the query executed successfully.

Keep in mind that “executed successfully” means that it ran without error; it
doesn’t mean that the query’s execution necessarily had the desired result; you’ll need to test for that.

**Then how to test?**

While the `mysqli_num_rows()` function will return the number of rows generated by a **SELECT** query, `mysqli_affected_rows()` returns the number of rows affected by an **INSERT**, **UPDATE**, or **DELETE** query. It’s used like so:

```
$num = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc);
```

Unlike `mysqli_num_rows()`, the one argument the function takes is the database connection (**$dbc**), not the results of the previous query (**$r**).

Answer (score 3):

After `INSERT` query you can use `ROW_COUNT()` to check for successful insert operation as:

```
SELECT IF(ROW_COUNT() = 1,  "Insert Success", "Insert Failed") As status;
```

Comment: Return true does not guarantee the data has been inserted into database, can I say so ?

Comment: yes, this is safest way as return true will not work in case of `INSERT IGNORE` query.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO PEOPLE (NAME ) VALUES ('COLE')")or die(mysql_error())) {
  echo 'Success';
} else {
  echo 'Fail';
}
```

Although since you have `or die(mysql_error())` it will show the mysql_error() on the screen when it fails. You should probably remove that if it isnt the desired result

Answer (score 2):

Check:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: Helpful, but please do not add a [link only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/).