# How to restrict MySQL/PHP to INSERT data if any notice occurs?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to `validate` my insert query. If the query successfully executed only then images attached will be uploaded to the server and returns the success message.

While doing so, I mistakenly passed the wrong variable to the `INSERT` query. It shows me the notice and inserted an empty record in the database and all the images attached with the form get uploaded with the success message.

> **Notice: Undefined variable: categry**
>
> Records Inserted Successfully

I tested the same even on server but still the same issue.

```
$category = "finance";

$sql = "INSERT into category (busi_cat) values ('".$category."')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
    echo "Records Inserted Successfully";
    move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
    createThumbnail($filename);
} 
else {
    die("Something went wrong. Please try again later.");
}
```

Reference Link:

**[Insert data to MySql DB and display if insertion is success or failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650160/insert-data-to-mysql-db-and-display-if-insertion-is-success-or-failure)**

What I want to do is if their is no **`WARNING`** or **`NOTICE`** only then, it inserts the record to the database and process further.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omitt insertion if $category is empty.

```
 if($category !="")
    {
        $sql = "INSERT into category (busi_cat) values ('".$category."')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

Comment: It's just any example. In actual have around 15-20 variables so should I have to validate each before insertion?

Comment: yes. Its good practice to validate the values before insert into database.

Comment: @balajimca your answer is right for me I just edited it and put an exit function dont you think its also a good practice to put it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo.

You are declaring `$category = "finance";` but then using `$categry` for your INSERT query. As PHP is complaining, $categry is undefined due to the typo.

Comment: Ok, why it is inserting an empty record into the database if their is no value found to be inserted.

Comment: PHP isn't my strongest suit, but as far as I can tell the query is expanding to: `INSERT into category (busi_cat) values ('')`. I believe that is what happens with an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

PHP gives you warning so that you can correct it. If you still want execution to be stopped then set_errror_handler will come in handy.

Suggestion: Do not use insert queries in such a way. SQL injections are possible. Use parameterized queries. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

balajimca's Answer is fine to me and I would just add  a simple exit function

```
if($category !="")
    {
        $sql = "INSERT into category (busi_cat) values ('".$category."')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
else{
echo "Any message here ";
/*And also add the exit function to avoid the program to proceed since it did not pass the requirements */
exit(); 
}
```