# jquery - get data from ajax POST method

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I use ajax to send form data to php script which save this data into mysql table. Here is jQuery

```
var postAction = $(form).attr('action');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: postAction,
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

This php script after insert data to mysql return html code.

```
<?php
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table ('id','name') VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."'); 
    if($query) echo "OK";
    else echo "ERROR";
?>
```

Now i need result of this php script ('OK' or 'ERROR') use in success function.

It is possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650160/insert-data-to-mysql-db-and-display-if-insertion-is-success-or-failure

Your code must work !

Comment: Or you want to show if insert it's ok in js ?

Comment: I want success function get result of php script, and use this result on page where the form was submited ex. $('div').html(data);

Comment: But you already have it! The data contains "OK" or "ERROR", so you can do whatever you want with those responses !

Comment: You got right. Sorry for my carelessness at work with my script :( Its my fault. In php script i include data which produce error. But what is weird, include same data in other script files  dont make any error.

Comment: Dont worry, vote my comments positive ! :)