# Search multiple words in differnt table at a time in Mysql php

Tags: php

0)  

       {  

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  

        { 

echo $company_data[] = $row;

        } 

             }  

          else  

           {  

       echo 'Data not Found';  

             }  

          }

             ?>

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where do we begin...

Comment: For starters If you insist on using a key word as a column name i.e. from you need to use backticks or come up with a better name.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Insert Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650160/insert-data-to-mysql-db-and-display-if-insertion-is-success-or-failure).

Your code should have condition-

`if ($rest)`

Comment: If you are trying to say that using if($query) is always going to be TRUE as it is a string... then can you correct you answer to say so :) and add that it should be if($rest)

Comment: I changed but not getting inserted

Comment: check `$con` variable has successful db connection, then check if your table **star_bith** has proper columns. Try running **$query** output directly on your mysql table.  Keep you error_reporting=on for your development code and check php error logs, it might help you.

Comment: INSERT INTO star_bith(starName,born,from,residence,nationality,education,occupation,tags,photo,userId) VALUES ('akshay','2017-07-17','aurangabad','pune','india','mca','acting','love,song','../starpic/09-07-2017-1499595736.jpg','1')

Comment: I checked in full but still did not database

Comment: How did you check in full? Are you using phpmyadmin or something similar to test the generated SQL statement to confirm it works?